# Trouble calling REST ws from android app

Tags: android, web-services, android-json

I'm calling a web service using the following code:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    int resCode;        

    String uri = "http://myServer:8080/api/activities/post";
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
    request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.setHeader("Accept","application/json");

    try{
        JSONStringer requestData = new JSONStringer()
           .object()
                .key("codeActivity").value("XLT-900")
                .key("firstValue").value("9")
                .key("secondValue").value("3")
           .endObject();

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestData.toString());
        request.setEntity(entity);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request); 
        resCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (resCode == 200) {
            return true;
        }else{
            Log.i("doInBackground","resCode: "+resCode);
            return false;
        }           

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

The json data that should be send is (I have verified that is correctly created):

```
{"codeActivity":"XLT-900","firstValue":"9","secondValue":"3"}
```

But I obtain always the result: **400: Bad request**

But if I call the same ws from POSTMAN or other similar application I obtain the status `200: Ok` that ensure that the ws woeks good.

So where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are you sure want to do a POST request?
2. Are you missing any headers, like authorization?
3. Try this:

   ```
   StringEntity se = new StringEntity(requestData.toString(), "UTF-8");
   se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
   ```

Comment: I obtain the same result

Comment: However, yes I need to use POST, and no authorization is required in my web service.